# How to stop html5 video when closing its inline popup, cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello fellow coders i come to you in a time of need. I have an inline popup containing html5 videos. i added a stop('#video'); to the "close popup" function and this works, but only in Chrome and Opera, not in Firefox and EI, which leads me to a sub question, based on the same code, can anyone se a reason why the video wont load properly in Opera and Safari. I cant for the life of me figure out why and im hoping one of you can.

HTML:

```
<section id="video">
    <a href="#" class="topopup">
        <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play company video" title="Play company Video"/>
    </a>

    <div id="toPopup">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div id="popup_content">
            <video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
                <source src="video/AM1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/AM2.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="video/AM3.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Video format not supported by your browser
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#video {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    /*light gray*/
}

#video img {
    width: 36.11%;
    max-width: 252px;
}

#backgroundPopup {
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#000000;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#toPopup {
    background: none repeat scroll #000;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    height:auto;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(this).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 27) // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
    disablePopup(); // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 27) stop('#video');

});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
    disablePopup(); //  close pop up

});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
    stop('#video'); // stop video
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, I'm a bit puzzled how your `stop` function worked anywhere at all--the way to stop an HTML5 video is by using `DOMNode.pause()`. Maybe I misunderstood your post?

Comment: Well no from your answer it sounds like you understood, i have read a  few places that stop('#video'); isnt a real function but i guess a few browser reconice it. But anyway i will try out DOMNode.pause() and then i will return to you

Comment: Sorry but i am kind of new, and i cant seem to get DOMNode.pause('#video'); to work in any browser, could you give an example of how to properly construct a DOMNode.pause function ?

Comment: Try this: `document.querySelector("video").pause();`.

Comment: Aswome ty so much, you just saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the video tag

than you can access the video DOM Object using Javascript

var videoControl = document.getElementById("myVideoPlayer");
videoControl.pause();